# reduction of "To" in pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

I can't hear "to" sound in these sentences:

> 1. It turns out that she is going **to** Daytona .....
> 2. Waking up next **to** people you don't even know.....

Why is it?
If you want to check it out it's from **Friends** season 6 episode 19, minute 15:00 in DVD version

Answer (score 2):

In native English series and movies, the pronunciation of words tends to be fast. So smaller sounds such as prepositions (to) might be pronounced very quickly, to the extent that it may be hard to hear.
This is especially true in your second example "next to ". Since the t is repeated, the person might only say the "t" of the next, and add a small o sound which might not even be very easy to hear.
In these cases, the meaning must be deduced.
Nonetheless learning how native speakers pronounce things is a great idea through movies and series.
Keep learning!